# Nginx: Rewrite all requests to HTTPS except one directory

Tags: http, nginx, https, url-rewriting

Morning,

I am new to Nginx and am having problems redirecting all requests to HTTPS except one directory which is needed to server up images over HTTP.

Basically a sample request to http://domain.com/images/logos/image.png should be served over HTTP and not HTTPS.

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
        location / {
                return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;  # enforce https
        }
        location /images/logos/ {
                ;
        }

}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name domain.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        root /var/www/apache/txtreme.co.uk/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

        location /images/logos/ {
                return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
        }

         }
         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what's the problem? I only see syntax errors, you could check them with `nginx -t`

Comment: Apologies I must of missed that off. I get a 404 not found on the images directory for some reason.

Comment: Oh, you've missed root directive

Comment: Is that to go in the location /images/logos/ { block?

Comment: Sorted now thank you very much. For any interested I had to add the root directive.